# What is the value of $e^{-10000}$?

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation, approximation, matlab

### What is the value of $e^{-10000}$?

We know that the function $e$ does not attain value $0$ anymore.

But in R and Matlab the value of $e^{-10000}$ is given as $0$ which is not correct anymore.

I understand theat this is happening only because of the rounding error in Matlab as well as in R.

could anyone help me in finding the exact value of $e^{-10000}$?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7B-10000%7D - click on approximate form. Here are more digits $1.135483865314736098540938875066248401957431610090318842671552659157305 \times 10^{-4343}$

Comment: I think that you don't mean *exact* value... The exact value of $e^{-10000}$ is $e^{-10000}$.

Comment: @RichardAmbler thats true

Comment: how to get this in Matlab or R???

Comment: The smallest value representable in double precision floating-point is `2^-1022` (`realmin` in Matlab) – your solution resolves to zero because it's much smaller than this. I suggest reading this: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 8):

$$\log_{10}(e^{-10000}) = -10000 * (0.4342944819) = -4342.944819$$

Thus, 
$$e^{-1000}=10^{ -4342.944819} = 10^{-4343} 10^{ 0.05518} = 1.13548386531 \times 10^{-4343}$$

Comment: Our approaches are basically the same, so I've withdrawn mine. Nicely done.

Comment: how to get this in Matlab or R???

Comment: Type in zero. :)

Comment: $x=10^4 log10(e); y=ceil(x);z=y-x;t=10^z$. Your answer is $t\times 10^{-y}$

Comment: @gloom: In Matlab you can use [variable precision arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) (assuming that you have the Symbolic Math toolbox): `exp(-vpa(10000))`.